# Session + another session

Tags: php, operators, session-variables

I have tried this:

```
$_SESSION['fullname'] = $_SESSION['firstname'] + $_SESSION['surname'];

echo $_SESSION['fullname'];
```

But it doesn't work :-(

Comment: did you added `session_start()` on the top of page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
$_SESSION['fullname'] = $_SESSION['firstname'] . $_SESSION['surname'];
//                                             ^
```

To concatenate strings you should use `.` not `+`.

Answer (score 0):

To combine strings use "." instead of "+"
$_SESSION['fullname'] = $_SESSION['firstname'] . $_SESSION['surname'];